# C#/SQL: Varbinary(max) column to DataGridView to Picturebox

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, picturebox

I am absolutely befuddled at the moment. Kind madams, good sirs; please do assist!

**This is what I am doing:**

I have a WinForms application connected to a SQL database with a varbinary(max) column for storing pictures.
In my parent form (*form1*), I have a DataGridView (*dgv1*). Double-clicking on any row will bring up a new form (*form2*), where I can edit the row data, and where there's also a PictureBox (*pb1*).

If I add a picture, and then go back and refresh the DataGridView, and try to open the same row, it'll give me this error message:

[image: errormessage]

If I go into the database and set the value of the varbinary(max) column back to NULL (from < Binary data >), and try to open the same row again, it'll work fine.

**Let me show you my code:**

```
// this runs when I double click a row in dgv1

ChildForm myChildForm = new ChildForm();
myChildForm.txt1.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
myChildForm.txt2.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
myChildForm.txt3.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

if (DBNull.Value != dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value) {
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
    myChildForm.pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(mStream);

myChildForm.ShowDialog();
```

```
// this is on a button, and how I send the edited info from *form2* to the database

byte[] imageData;

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream()) {

        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", txt1.Text.ToString());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", txt2.Text.ToString());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", txt2.Text.ToString());

        imageData = mStream.ToArray();
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter3", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imageData;
        pb1.Image.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If anyone can give me any hints as to what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate that a bunch! Thanks!

Comment: why are you trying to insert a null array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off `imageData` is going to be an empty `byte[]` because you're copying from the MemoryStream before you write the image data to the stream.

```
imageData = mStream.ToArray();
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter3", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imageData;
pb1.Image.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

At a minimum, write the data to the MemoryStream before copying it to the `byte[]` and create the SqlParameter properly.

```
pb1.Image.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imageData = mStream.ToArray();
var pImg = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter3",SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
pImg.Value = imageData;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir David Browne of Microsoft. That did the trick!

Comment: Did you know you can do `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter3", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = imageData;`

Comment: Yep.  So long as you don’t need to set the Direction or other properties.  Raw ADO.NET should be verbose.  Otherwise use Dapper or EF.